# Read data from closed excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to fetch data from a closed excel file. As I understand, you need to give the whole path of the file in the formula for excel to be able to read the data without having the file open first.

I tried the following formula in Excel, and it works.

```
=VLOOKUP(C10, 'F:\Data\Project\0 Data\14 Equipment Fabricated\0 Data\Data - Fabrication items - Purchase rate & Labor rate.xlsx'!Data_TallyItem, MATCH("Rate, Rs./UOM (Purchase)", 'F:\Data\Project\0 Data\14 Equipment Fabricated\0 Data\Data - Fabrication items - Purchase rate & Labor rate.xlsx'!HDR_TallyItem, 0), FALSE)
```

However, when I put the same code in VBA, it didn't work when the target file is closed but worked when the target file is open.

```
Function getRate(item As Range) as Double
    getRate = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(item, Range("'F:\Data\Project\0 Data\14 Equipment Fabricated\0 Data\Data - Fabrication items - Purchase rate & Labor rate.xlsx'!Data_TallyItem"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Rate, Rs./UOM (Purchase)", Range("'F:\Data\Project\0 Data\14 Equipment Fabricated\0 Data\Data - Fabrication items - Purchase rate & Labor rate.xlsx'!HDR_TallyItem"), 0), False)
End Function
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Actually EXCEL opens the file in the background (most of the time it asks 'This workbook contains links.... Update /Don't Update, etc.), refreshes ('updates links') the values,and closes them. When you use it in VBA you are on your own; you can still open it, evaluate the function, and close it.